# Hide template ng-view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on an application that uses AngularJS. We are using an index.html file that shows up on every page, there is one page where it should not show. How can I hide the index.html file from showing up on a specific page? Will greatly appreciate any suggestions/answers

EDIT

This is the template I would like to remove:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="agentSupportApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <script src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app/fonts.css">
    <!-- things related to bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- things related to angular -->
    <script src="js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap lib for angular -->
    <script src="js/lib/bootstrap/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- things related to internationalization -->
    <script src="js/lib/i18next/i18next-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/ng-i18next/ng-i18next.js"></script>

    <!-- application related files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app/error.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app/customer_info.css">

    <script src="js/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/config.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app/factories.js"></script>

    <!--directives go here -->
    <script src="js/app/directives/active-menu.js"></script>
    <!-- Services go here-->
    <script src="js/app/services/rest_service.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers go here -->
    <script src="js/app/controllers/error-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/controllers/lang-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/controllers/user-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/controllers/nav-controller.js"></script>

    <!-- screen specific contollers go here-->
    <script src="js/app/controllers/drive-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/controllers/drive-user-controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div ng-include src="'views/common/topbar.html'"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row view-margin">
            <div ng-view="" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div ng-include src="'views/common/footer.html'"/>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

app.js file:

```
  (function(){
"use strict";

var agentSupportApp = angular.module('agentSupportApp',[
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngResource',
    'subscriptionControllers',
    'jm.i18next',
    'ui.bootstrap'
    ]);

/**
* CONTROLLER Modules are defined here
*/
angular.module('subscriptionControllers',[]);

/****END OF CONTROLLERS****/

agentSupportApp.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.version = '1.0';
    /*$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(){
        console.log('Event fired');
    });*/
}]);

/* Routing mapping to fetch a particular template when wanted*/
agentSupportApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    //USED
    when('/error',{templateUrl:'views/common/error.html', controller:'MessageController'}).
    when('/dashboard',{templateUrl:'views/dashboard.html'}).
    when('/drive',{templateUrl:'views/drive_support.html', controller:'DriveController'}).
    when('/userdetail',{templateUrl:'views/drive_user_detail.html', controller:'DriveUserController'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo:'/dashboard'});
}]);

}());
```

Comment: Can you paste some code of what you got so far? :) thanks!

Comment: Yeah very likely you can get by with just using ng-hide and some boolean but you also might make use of ui-router for more complex view  requirements

Comment: ok I have added some code

Answer (score 0):

Use $location to get the Route Url

Using combination of $location and ng-hide/ng-show you can hide the page.

eg: Suppose url is the variable storing the value of your URL. You can use

```
<div ng-hide="url==<URL WHERE YOU WANT TO HIDE THE HTML>">
</div>
```